# IE6 z-index on two absolutely positionned divs

Tags: html, css

I got tired facing IE6 Bugs.
The issue, is two (position:absolute) divs are not working properly on their z-index:
Considering the following example;

```
/* css */
#overlay{
    position:absolute;
    height:1200px;
    z-index:2;
    top:expression(eval(document.compatMode && document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat') ? documentElement.scrollTop+(documentElement.clientHeight-this.clientHeight) : document.body.scrollTop+(document.body.clientHeight-this.clientHeight));
}

#dropping_list{
    position:absolute;
    top:34px;
    left:0;
    padding:0;
    width:635px;
    max-height:455px;
    background:#FFF;
    display:none;
    overflow:auto;
    z-index:3;
}

<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="dropping_list">some content here</div>
```

But i got ovelay above #droping_list!
Any help would be so much appreciated;

For more information you can see it in action at:
http://www.monde-presse.com

On the search form at the top, type in **tion** and hit enter to get some results for the test.

Barry

Answer (score 0):

Re-arrange your elements:

from:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="dropping_list">some content here</div>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="dropping_list">some content here</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, in fact they already are like so, arranged as you mentionned, Question edited -